# Stored procedure with dynamic SQL and ORDER BY

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-order-by, dynamic-sql

I have built a stored procedure that aims to identify duplicates in a table and to display the duplicated rows in a meaningful order. It looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spFindDuplicates] 
    @tableName nvarchar(255), 
    @field1 nvarchar(255), 
    @field2 nvarchar(255) = '1', 
    @field3 nvarchar(255) = '2', 
    @field4 nvarchar(255) = '3', 
    @field5 nvarchar(255) = '4'

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @query AS nvarchar(MAX);

SET @query = '
SELECT *
FROM ' + @tableName + '
WHERE CAST(' + @field1 + ' AS nvarchar(255)) + CAST(' + @field2 + ' AS nvarchar(255)) + CAST(' + @field3 + ' AS nvarchar(255)) + CAST(' + @field4 + ' AS nvarchar(255)) + CAST(' + @field5 + ' AS nvarchar(255)) 
IN 
(
    SELECT CAST(' + @field1 + ' AS nvarchar(255)) + CAST(' + @field2 + ' AS nvarchar(255)) + CAST(' + @field3 + ' AS nvarchar(255)) + CAST(' + @field4 + ' AS nvarchar(255)) + CAST(' + @field5 + ' AS nvarchar(255))
    FROM ' + @tableName + '
    GROUP BY CAST(' + @field1 + ' AS nvarchar(255)) + CAST(' + @field2 + ' AS nvarchar(255)) + CAST(' + @field3 + ' AS nvarchar(255)) + CAST(' + @field4 + ' AS nvarchar(255)) + CAST(' + @field5 + ' AS nvarchar(255))
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
ORDER BY ' + @field1 + ', ' + @field2 + ', ' + @field3 + ', ' + @field4 + ', ' + @field5

EXECUTE(@query);

END

GO

--Example:

EXEC spFindDuplicates @tableName = 'someRandomTable', @field1 = 'firstField', @field2 = 'secondField', @field3 = 'thirdField'
```

As you can see, I can use at most 5 different fields that I concatenate in order for me to get a key used to determine whether we have a duplicate or not. Please note that I use the CAST function to be able to concatenate fields with various datatypes (varchar, int, dates, etc.).

When I execute the above stored procedure with 5 different fields, it works fine. But I would like to be able to run it with a variable number of fields (from 1 to 5), which is why I provided default values for @field2 to @field5.

But when I execute it with the above example (3 fields provided), I get the following error message:

> A column has been specified more than once in the order by list. Columns in the order by list must be unique.

**QUESTION:** How can I keep ordering the resulting table without getting an error?

**BONUS QUESTION:** If you find a dynamic way to use that stored procedure with any number of fields (4, 17, or whatever), that'd be even more useful to me.

Comment: you can do that dynamically, by using single column param where you will pass comma separated columns or with table types

Comment: What you have there has a huge security flaw; it's wide open to SQL Injection. You should be parameterising your query, by using `sp_executesql` and quoting your objects by using `QUOTENAME`. Right now you just have a vulnerability waiting to be exploited.

Comment: you are getting error because at the end you have ORDER BY firstField, secondField, thirdField, 3, 4. So the 3rd fields is ordered 2 times

Comment: @Larnu Let's consider I don't mind about SQL injection :) But thank you for raising that issue.

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev I don't think that's the real issue because it tried other default values and the same error message kept popping up.

Comment: *"Larnu Let's consider I don't mind about SQL injection"* Impossible. you do. If you don't, then have a rethink, change your mind, and then fix the problem.

Comment: If this isn't an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) I don't know what is.

Comment: you can PRINT @query variable and you'll see the exact query

Comment: So, you want to *allow* duplicate rows in many of your tables but you also need to identify those duplicates on a regular basis? Are you sure you're solving the right problem? Because more normally, it indicates you need some unique constraints to stop the duplicates from existing in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Like I said in the comments, injection is a huge problem here, and you need to consider it. Saying *"Let's consider I don't mind about injection"* is naïve and you need to change that attitude. Always make your SQL safe; then there are no excuses and chances for your application being compromised.

As what you are after, I *suspect* this achieves the goal. There's no need for the subquery to scan your table with an `IN` here, you can make use of `COUNT` and the `OVER` clause within a CTE.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FindDuplicates] --I've removed te sp prefix, as sp_ is reserved by MS
    @tableName sysname, 
    @field1 sysname, 
    @field2 sysname = NULL, 
    @field3 sysname = NULL, 
    @field4 sysname = NULL, 
    @field5 sysname = NULL

AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @query AS nvarchar(MAX);

    SET @query = N'WITH CTE AS(' + NCHAR(10) +
                 N'    SELECT *' + NCHAR(10) + 
                 N'           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ' + STUFF(CONCAT(N',' + QUOTENAME(@field1),N',' + QUOTENAME(@field2),N',' + QUOTENAME(@field3),N',' + QUOTENAME(@field4),N',' + QUOTENAME(@field5)),1,1,N'') + N' AS RowCount' + NCHAR(10) +
                 N'    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + N')' + NCHAR(10) +
                 N'SELECT *' + NCHAR(10) +
                 N'FROM CTE' + NCHAR(10) +
                 N'WHERE RowCount > 1' + NCHAR(10) + 
                 N'ORDER BY ' + STUFF(CONCAT(N',' + QUOTENAME(@field1),N',' + QUOTENAME(@field2),N',' + QUOTENAME(@field3),N',' + QUOTENAME(@field4),N',' + QUOTENAME(@field5)),1,1,N'') + N';';

    PRINT @query;
    --EXEC sys.sp_executesql @query; --Uncomment to rrun the actual query
END
GO
```

For the command you gave us `EXEC dbo.FindDuplicates @tableName = 'someRandomTable', @field1 = 'firstField', @field2 = 'secondField', @field3 = 'thirdField';`, this returns the SQL:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [firstField],[secondField],[thirdField] AS RowCount
    FROM [someRandomTable])
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RowCount > 1
ORDER BY [firstField],[secondField],[thirdField];
```

Which, I *believe* gives you the behaviour you are after.

Comment: Well done. Took me a second to figure out how you handled NULLs but that is pretty clever.

Comment: `CONCAT` and `STUFF` works a dream for NULLable parameters, and similar, @SeanLange. To explain for others (maybe i should put in the answer), `CONCAT` (unlike normal string concatenation) doesn't return `NULL` when one of the expressions has the value `NULL`. So `'a' + NULL` would be `NULL`, however, `CONCAT('a',NULL, NULL, 'b')` would be `'ab'`. I use that to "my" advantage, meaning that the `NULL` value parameters are effectively "discarded" when building the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses

Comment: Yeah I just had never considered using like this. Pretty cool.

Answer (score -2):

Edited the code to check if the column list exists on the sys.columns there by making sure we get only the columns which are appropriate.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_SplitString
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spFindDuplicates] 
    @tableName nvarchar(255), 
    @columnlist nvarchar(max)  

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @query AS nvarchar(MAX);

SET @columnlist = (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ','+'['+[name]+']'
FROM SYS.columns
WHERE object_id = object_id(@tableName)
AND [Name] IN
(
   SELECT Item
   FROM dbo.fn_SplitString(@columnlist,',')
)
FOR XML PATH('')
)
,1,1,''))

PRINT @columnlist

SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT '+CAST(@columnlist AS NVARCHAR(MAX))+'
FROM '+CAST(@tableName AS nvarchar(MAX))+'
GROUP BY '+CAST(@columnlist AS NVARCHAR(MAX))+'
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)Res1
ORDER BY '+@columnlist


EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query;

END

GO
```

Comment: This is far from going to solve the injection issue. In fact, `ORDER BY '+@columnlist` makes it even worse; as that is impossible to "make safe".

Comment: @Dheerendra Your suggestion is almost good but the 'SELECT *' is important to me, which is why I need to use a subquery and to concatenate fields. And in that case, your code is failing when it comes to concatenating

Comment: @Guillaume - I have edited the code. An i think to eliminate the sql injection, we can split the columns from the column list and match with the columns of the sys.columns and consider only the one's which are being match and update the comma seperated list as an enhancement to the procedure

Comment: The edit does not make this safe from sql injection. It is wide open.

Comment: @SeanLange - Edited the code for column check. Suggest if this would eliminate the sql injection upto some extent

Comment: Using a while loop to split strings is just awful. I realize you copy and pasted this. [Here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) are several much better ways to deal with splitting strings. An even better way would be to use table valued parameters instead so you don't have to parse it at all.

Comment: Edited to reflect the same

Comment: FYI. as well `'['+[name]+']'` doesn't properly quote an object's name. Although someone would be *"foolish"* to do so, an object *can* have a right bracket `]` in its name (and I have seen objects where that is true /facepalm). The method you have would "break" if someone was "silly" enough to do so. Ideally, rather than `'['+[name]+']'` use `QUOTENAME([name])` (though I suppose `N'['+REPLACE([name],N']',N']]')+N']'` would work too).

Comment: Good to know @Larnu. Thank you for the suggestion